# Migrating Carrierwave to ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, rails-migrations, rails-activestorage

I have an application using Carrierwave to handle file uploads but really love the simplicity of ActiveStorage. There are plenty of tutorials on migrating from Paperclip to ActiveStorage with the former sunsetting development, but I see nothing on migrating from Carrierwave to ActiveStorage. Has anyone successfully done the migration and could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 14):

The procedure is really simple actually.

### step 1:

configure the active store bucket. try to use a different bucket than your carrierwave one

### step 2:

configure your model in order to provide access to the ActiveStorage. example

```
 class Photo < AR::Base

   mount_uploader :file, FileUploader # this is the current carrierwave implementation. Don't remove it 

   has_one_attached :file_new # this will be your new file 

 end
```

Now you will have two implementations for the same model. carrierwave access at `file` and ActiveStorage at `file_new`

## step 3:

download images from Carrierwave and save it to active storage
This can be implemented in a rake file, activeJob etc..

```
 Photo.find_each do |photo|
   begin
   filename = File.basename(URI.parse(photo.fileurl))
   photo.file_new.attach(io: open(photo.file.url), filename: d.file )
   rescue => e
   ## log/handle your errors in order to retry later
   end
 end
```

At this point you will have one image on the carrierwave bucket and the newly created image on the active storage bucket!

## (optional)

### step 4

Once you are ready with the migration modify your model changing the active storage accessor and remove the carrierwave integration

```
 class Photo < AR::Base
   has_one_attached :file # we changed the atachment name from file_new to file 
 end
```

This is a convenience option so your integration in controllers and other places remain intact. hopefully!

### step 5

Update your records on `active_storage_attachments` table in order for the attachments be found as `file` and not `file_new` update column `name` from "file_new" to "file"

#### notes

Is possible to make some other tweaks to the application in order to handle things to consider

- if your site will be running while you do the migration one way to fully operate would be implement active storage for new uploads then when you display images you can display active storage and carrierwave as a fallback

something like this in a helper:

`photo.attached? ? url_for(photo.file_new) : photo.file.url`

I hope this helps!

Comment: That rake task is much simpler than what I had started to cook up, thank you. I'll give this a shot and let you know how it goes.

Comment: having an issue with the suggested rake task. Running it as is gives me the following error message: (bad URI(is not URI?): https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/***/***/***.jpg) though I know the image is there. In fact, if I open the specified link in a browser, it gives me the option to download it. I modified the code to encode the uri first before parsing but then receive 'undefined method 'gsub' for #<PodcastUploader:***>' but gsub isn't used in the uploader.

Comment: `def store_dir`  
    `if Rails.env.development?`  
      `"development/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.slug.to_s}"`  
    `else`  
      `"#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.slug.to_s}"`  
    `end`  
  `end`

Comment: I'm a bit of an amateur and am not sure about Step 3. How do I run that? rake files and ActiveJobs are beyond my knowledge. OK, guides are good. I ran `bin/rails generate job copy-carrierwave-to-activestorage`. I think I can work with your `Photo.find…` but not obvious to me which file to put it in nor how to run it when I've done that. The files are `app/jobs/copy_carrierwave_to_activestorage_job.rb` and `spec/jobs/copy_carrierwave_to_activestorage_job_spec.rb` and `app/jobs/application_job.rb`. I appreciate this post, not seeing anything else on migrating.

Comment: Have you actually tried your code? The attach() line in my equivalent of your step #3 `photo.file_new.attach()` crashes with: `NoMethodError (undefined method 'upload' for nil:NilClass)`. There seems to be an issue with the blob not being signed? If anyone has a working solution, please, share.

Comment: Has anyone successfully migrated from Carrierwave to ActiveStorage here?

Answer (score 2):

To begin with

1. You'll have to run this `bundle exec rails active_storage:install`
2. `rails db:migrate`
3. Replace `mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader`, to look like `has_one_attached :image`, in your model.
4. For rendering the image in the view, you should replace `image_url` with `url_for(user.image)`.

You don't have to make any change to the controller code or in params, as the attribute `image` is already a **strong** parameter.

```
# user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  has_one_attached :image
end

# show.html.erb
<%= image_tag url_for(user.image) %>
or
<%= image_tag user.image %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Definitely useful for the initial setup which I had already done, but I was looking to migrate existing records from Carrierwave to ActiveStorage.

Comment: Are you storing the images on cloud, service such as **s3** ?

Comment: digital ocean actually, but it does use the s3 sdk.

Comment: What if we already have thousands of file uploads already deployed on Heroku via S3?  How to manage that type of transfer?